# Modeling database for a browser game

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, database-design

I work on a browser game developed with symfony for school project.

In my schema I have a table player and a table inventory (which contains different items) with relation one-to-one.

I'm not sure how I can build the table inventory. After reflexion, I have find two ways to do this :

1.

```
TABLE inventory
  id
  id_player
  item1
  item2
  item3
  ...
```

But if I want add an item in the game, I have to add a column to my table and if there are a lot of items, I will have many columns.

2.

```
TABLE inventory
  id
  id_player
  item
  quantity
```

I think this way is better, but the number of records will quickly increase because I have one line by player by item.

There are other methods which are more efficient ? If not, which is the better in the both ?

Comment: This is simple database normalization - the first structure is simply wrong - the second is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second approach should be fine, as long as there's an index on id_player. I wouldn't worry about its space usage. If each row takes 25 bytes and each player has 400 types of items and you have 1 million users, that's still just 10 gigs.

Comment: What he said ;). Don't worry about disk space (yet), worry about speed.

Comment: yes, I'm not afraid by disk space, but by time to retrieve selected rows

Comment: I see... it's certainly slower than storing a player's inventory in one cell (which could work, although your #2 is more elegant), but at least there's minimal context switching needed to grab a player's inventory (a single SELECT). So there's just the cost of searching a B-tree, following a pointer for each row and copying the data... I think it would be reasonably fast.

Answer (score 4):

To complete the above answer, you could add a table with your items, and then just change your **item** columns to **id_item**.

```
TABLE player     
  id
  player_name
  ... player characteristics ...

TABLE inventory
  id
  id_player
  id_item
  quantity

TABLE item
  id
  item_name
  ... item characteristics ...
```

Comment: If I do this, I will have `user <> character <> inventory <> item`. It will be slowly, no ?